# Findings the dot product between two non-adjacent vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

I need to find $r\circ(p-q)$ from the below diagram, and since $r$ is prependicular to $p$, I only need to calculate $-(r\circ q)$ when I know that the modulus of $q=3$ and of $p=4$. Now, I know that $r$ isn't adjacent to $p$, however, if they were to be "connected" the angle between them would be $60$ degrees (from triangle calculations), but my textbook tells me the angle between them is $120$ degrees. I can't see why my textbook has added $30$ degrees onto $90$ to obtain the angle between them.

Here is the diagram:

[image]

And here is what I have tried:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extend the line DA so that it intersects with CB extended you can see that the angle between $q$ and $r$ is 120

Comment: I extended them both and found that the angle was again $60$ degrees because if we extend them we will have a right angled triangle with angles $30$ and $90$ and $60$.m

Comment: The angle is 120 because the arrows point away from the point of intersection, and between them the angle is 120. The angle between $r$ and $-q$ or betwen $-r$ and $q$ is 60